# Sync Laravel Local mysql database with LIVE server database manual code from Local system using CRON job and CURL

Tags: php, mysql, curl, cron, laravel-8

I want local database sync with live database using CURL and CRON job in LARAVEL not using third party tool manual code

Answer (score 0):

it is almost a complicated issue. you need to pay attention to a bunch of concepts :

**[CAP Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)**

> In the CAP theorem, also named Brewer's theorem, we know that any
> distributed data store can only provide two of the following three
> guarantees:

- **Consistency**

Every read receives the most recent write or an error.

- **Availability**

Every request receives a (non-error) response, without the guarantee that it contains the most recent write.

- **Partition tolerance**

The system continues to operate despite an arbitrary number of messages being dropped (or delayed) by the network between nodes.

since you have Partition tolerance in your desired situation, so your problem is the choice between consistency and high availability.

I mentioned this theorem to notice you that you cant have any guaranty for having them both in WHATEVER solution you asking for.

anyway ...

the Databases availability and consistency issues are one of the tops arguments in the world of information technology. there are several ways for achieving such a purpose, for example using :

- implementation clustering
- master/slave - master/master - active/passive - active-active - etc architectures
- using changelogs for keeping two DB sync
- implementing CDC or some structure like it
- and every other solution.

so I must say that your issue cant be satisfy without using third-party libraries of some system-level configuration, you cant do it with just a simple CURL.

but if you insist to do it with the nearest approach to curl, you can use **NFS**, by getting SQL backup and loading it instead of your local one.

Comment: Can you please send me complete code with step by step so I can get better idea using CURL? What is NFS?

Comment: NFS = Network File Sharing / unfortunately I can't write such a step-by-step tutorial here, it needs systems specialty or R&D that you must do.

Comment: Great information / tnx @behzadmsalehi